# Find a function $f$ such that $f$ is discontinuous but $W(f,x)$ is a continuous function

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, multivariable-calculus, continuity, upper-lower-bounds

I need some help

Find a function $f$ such that $f$ is discontinuous but $W(f,x)$ is a continuous function (where $W(f,x)$ is the oscillation of f in a point, this means that $W(f,x)=inf[M_\delta(f)-m_\delta(f)$  |  $\delta > 0]$

At first, I thought that the Dirichlet function could help since it is not continuous but I want to prove that $W(f,x)=0$ so this means the oscillation is continuous, some advice, please

Answer (score 1):

For the Dirichlet function $f := 1_{\Bbb{Q}}$, $W(f, x) = 1$ for all $x$. Since for this function, $W(f, x)$ is constant and equal to $1$ for all $x$, $W(f, x)$ is continuous for all $x$.

Comment: The Dirichlet Function is both $f=1_\mathbb{Q}$ and $f=0_\mathbb{I}$ so is continuos only on 1 or 0  but no both

Comment: @IvanBravo The Dirichlet function $f$ is discontinuous everywhere, because $W(f, x) = 1$ for all $x$. But $W(f, x) = 1$ for all $x$ means $W(f, x)$ is continuous for all $x$.

Comment: So that function works?

Comment: @Ivan Bravo: *So that function works?* --- Although what follows is a bit round-about, maybe it will help. Letting $g$ be defined by $g(x) = W(f,x),$ find an explicit formula for $W(g,x).$ What does the result tell you about the continuity of $g$?

Comment: @ivan bravo Yes.